# How much data can NumPy handle

Tags: numpy, pytables

I am trying to work with `PyTables` and `NumPy`.

Can you please tell me how much data the latter can handle?

I am currently handling data of 140 million rows and would like to know if `NumPy` can handle it. It would be nice if it could at least handle 140 million rows of 2 columns. Right now i use a 64-bit version of Windows with 8 GB of RAM.

If `NumPy` cannot handle this amount of data, what are the possible alternatives for statistics and machine learning algorithmic implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

140M is much less than 2**31, so this should even fit in a 32-bit Python/Numpy given sufficient memory. You can easily try this out with

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.empty((140e6, 2))
```

The memory use with the standard `dtype=np.float64` is on the order of 8 bytes × 140M × 2 = 2GB. If you use `dtype=np.float32` you can save a factor 2.